# Loading scripts to the Post Edit page only

Tags: custom-field, theme-development, metabox, wp-enqueue-script

I have added a few meta boxes for the posts and pages, so I want to load a js script only on the Create/Edit post and page. How can I do that?
Currently I'm using following but that loads the scripts in all pages in the admin.

```
function my_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box("post_meta", "Meta", "post_meta", "post", "normal", "high");
    add_meta_box("post_meta", "Meta", "post_meta", "page", "normal", "high");

}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_meta_boxes' );

function register_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/meta/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/meta/custom.css');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_custom_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can improve a little bit with :

```
function specific_enqueue($hook_suffix) {
   if( 'post.php' == $hook_suffix || 'post-new.php' == $hook_suffix ) {
     wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/meta/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ));
     wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/meta/custom.css')
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'specific_enqueue' );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have same problem, I get NULL value for `$hook_suffix`, thats why the condition doesn't become true and it doesn't load the scripts. I must be doing something wrong. Do I need to define `$hook_suffix` somewhere?

Comment: I've edited code see if it's working

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I didn't realize that I was using `admin_init` instead of `admin_enqueue_scripts`. Thanks again.

Comment: @jay yes you need to use **admin_enqueue_scripts**, I have mentioned it in the first line of my answer. Glad that you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use admin_enqueue_scripts hook to enqueue scripts to the admin pages and to make it to specific page follow the below:--

```
function specific_enqueue( $hook ) {
    if( 'post.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/meta/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/meta/custom.css')
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'specific_enqueue' );
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not seem to work. I checked `var_dump($hook);` and I get empty string. Do I need to define `$hook` somewhere?

Comment: Both the answers should work. and when you var_dump it you should see the file it is rendering.

Edited the answer Please check

Answer (score -2):

I have another approach which requires less code. As you are adding the scripts to work with metaboxes, you can equeue the scripts in the `add_meta_boxes()` action hook. It works perfectly and you don't need to check the actual page in every request for the admin area.

```
function my_meta_boxes() {

    add_meta_box("post_meta", "Meta", "post_meta", "post", "normal", "high");
    add_meta_box("post_meta", "Meta", "post_meta", "page", "normal", "high");
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/meta/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/meta/custom.css');

}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: hook to enqueue stylesheets & scripts in admin is `admin_enqueue_scripts`

Comment: Thats is not always needed and it is not always de best option. Although it depends on the situation, the purpose of the plugin (private/commercial) and the person who maintain the website. But, these words can be in the "opinion based" side.